# Spring Data Rest Association GET Override

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Okay, The answer to this question may be in the spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/) or [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/api/), but I have not been able to find it.
I am trying to implement a soft-delete.
and so far it is all working fine and dandy. Except when I get records by association.

example:
`http://localhost:8080/api/accounts` returns a proper list of accounts (not showing any accounts where is_deleted = true)

and
`http://localhost:8080/api/addresses` returns a proper list of addresses(not showing any addresses where `is_deleted = true`)

but when I hit `http://localhost:8080/api/accounts/3c84cdb1-6a01-4364-a60b-305afc521440/addresses`  I get a list of all addresses. even the ones where `is_deleted = true`

here is my custom baseRepository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID> extends JpaRepository<T,ID>{
    void obliterateEntity(T entity);


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.isDeleted = false")
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.isDeleted = false")
    List<T> findAll(Sort var1);

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.isDeleted = false")
    List<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> var1);

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.isDeleted = false")
    List<T> findAll();

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.isDeleted = false and e.id = ?1")
    Optional<T> findById(ID var1);

    @Query("update #{#entityName} e set e.isDeleted=true where e.id = ?1")
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void delete(UUID id);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    default void delete(T entity) {
        delete(entity.getId());
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**
Which method(s) do I need to override in order to filter deleted records when obtained through association links?

p.s. I also tried doing this instead of overriding the functions:

```
@SQLDelete(sql =
        "UPDATE address " +
                "SET is_deleted = true " +
                "WHERE id = ?")
@Loader(namedQuery = "findAddressById")
@NamedQuery(name= "findAddressById", query =
        "SELECT add " +
                "FROM Address add " +
                "WHERE " +
                "add.id = ?1 AND " +
                "add.isDeleted = false")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {
```

but that requires the same thing to be done in every single entity.  It also has other implementation problems.

I guess I am just having trouble doing soft-delete. So, any additional advice would be appreciated.

Comment: On `findAllById` do you mean to have `e.isDeleted = true`?

Comment: oh good catch. :)  Sadly though, that was not the culprit. I have edited my post

Comment: I have worked out a solution. I will post on Monday.

Comment: Here is how I ended up doing it:
- removed the delete override s from the base repo.
- And annotated every entity class as follows:
```@SQLDelete(sql =
        "UPDATE address " +
                "SET is_deleted = true " +
                "WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {```

Comment: If you've solved the problem, you can answer your own question. It may seem odd, but it's an accepted and even encouraged aspect of the site.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to, but thought about it. and Alan's answer was the solution to my original question.   There are some other changes I made as well, but they didn't relate directly to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the `@Where` on the association.

```
public class Account extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany
    @Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
    private Set<Address> addresses;
}
```

The `@Where` you have added to `Address` will only have an effect on directly loading addresses (and would seem to be redundant given the queries you have defined to load the data).

See section 4:

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-dynamic-mapping

Comment: I understand that is is redundant in some cases.   This link explains the why in some cases both are needed.
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-soft-delete-with-hibernate/

Comment: Well, okay but that is neither here nor there. Annotating the asociation as suggested  should address your primary problem. No?

Comment: I made some other changes to my end solution as well,  but you where correct.  The where annotation is what i really needed to get them via the entity association.  Thank you  :)
NOTE: This is a Hibernate specific fix.  So if anyone reading this needs a spring only fix, I am sorry.  :(

Comment: to clarify why this is the answer:
`Which method(s) do I need to override in order to filter deleted records when obtained through association links?`
there is none.  Spring is building a query in the background, and by adding the Where annotation, it forces spring to include this extra Where statement.